# Typescript, how to transform an object to an expeced form

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert or transform an object to the other object, which I want to.

inout object looks like that:

```
[
  {0: {contact: {
    1: {
      name: abc,
      address: street
     },
   2: {
      name: kdf,
      address: streedsd 
     }

   }
 }
}
{4: {education: {
    0: {
      uni: ssdabc,
      address: street
     },
   1: {
      uni: sdaskdf,
      address: streedsd 
     }

   }
 }
}
]
```

what I expeced is:

```
[
  {contact: [
     {
      name: abc,
      address: street
     },
    {
      name: kdf,
      address: streedsd 
     }

   ]
 }

{education: {
    [ {
      name: abc,
      address: street
     },
    {
      name: kdf,
      address: streedsd 
     }

   ]
 }
]
```

any solutions??? for the best, need a dynamic method, not only for contact.
this input object will be generated dynamically.

Comment: What's the issue about TypeScript? Just walk object as usual. Try [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` to iterate over the outer array and `Object.values()` to get values as array for the `contact` property.

```js
const data = [{
    contact: {
      0: {
        name: 'abc',
        address: 'street'
      },
      1: {
        name: 'kdf',
        address: 'streedsd'
      }

    }
  },
  {
    education: {
      0: {
        uni: 'ssdabc',
        address: 'street'
      },
      1: {
        uni: 'sdaskdf',
        address: 'streedsd'
      }

    }
  }
]


const convertedData = data.map(datum => {
  Object.keys(datum).forEach(key => {
    datum[key] = Object.values(datum[key])
  })
  
  return datum;
})

console.log('Converted Data:',convertedData)
console.log('Original Data:', data)
```

**Important**

Be aware that this method modifies the original data. If you don't want to modify the original, you can use `Array.reduce()` instead of `Array.map()`

Comment: thx for your solution, but how about to convert a dynamic input object?? I have edited my example again.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it generic.

Comment: I have also a qustion, how about, if the key is not 0 at the begining. such as my new edited data

Comment: I have changed input object.

Comment: Your last edited input is invalid. There's no such concept as `associative array` in JS.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, I have changed the example data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to extract the values of an object into a list.

Here is a code snippet that applies that to each item in your input:

*(Various changes have been made to input and outputs in the question, some of them are invalid json but this works for a fixed version of the latest edit)*

```js
const input = [{
  contact: {
    0: {
      name: "abc",
      address: "street"
    },
    1: {
      name: "kdf",
      address: "streedsd"
    }
  }
}, {
  education: {
    0: {
      uni: "ssdabc",
      address: "street"
    },
    1: {
      uni: "sdaskdf",
      address: "streedsd"
    }
  }
}]

const output = input.map(item => Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => ({
    [key]: Object.values(value)
  })))


console.log(output)
```

Comment: thx, but I have also a question, how about to change this method to a dynamic mehtod, that means, not only for contact

Comment: It depends whether your objects are list of objects, or lists of objects of lists, it isn't very clear. If you could copy some actual json into your question that would help